# How can I fetch .gitmodules directly into its github repository?

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, git-submodules

I know I can `git clone --recurse-submodules` to fetch the `.gitmodules` into the clone and then commit the result back to `github`, but I'm working with `colab` which doesn't (to my knowledge) provide such niceties in executing notebooks.  So I'd like to modify the repo on `github` without the (admittedly not too bad) extra step of cloning onto my system to do the desired modification and doing the commit.